# Acts_as_taggable gem: How to display thumbnails of posts with same tag on each post's show page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogs, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm struggling with the acts_as_taggable gem for my Rails 4 blog and hoping someone might point me in the right direction. Within each post's show view, I currently display the tags. But underneath the tags I want to display previews of posts with the same tags ("Read more posts about XYZ:"). Here's the code I have, which doesn't work:

**tags_controller.rb:**

```
def index
    @tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all
    @posts = Post.tagged_with(@tag.name)
    @related_posts = Post.tagged_with(@tag, :on => :tags)
end
```

**posts_controller.rb:**

```
def index
  if params[:tag]
     @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  else
     @posts = Post.all
  end
  . 
  .
  .
end
```

**views/posts/show.html.erb**

```
   <%= image_tag @post.image.url(:large) %>
   <%= @post.title %>
   <%= @post.subtitle %>
   <%= @post.body.html_safe %>
   <h3>Read more posts about: <%= render @post.tags %></h3>

   <!-- This is where I want to display related posts: -->
   <%= render 'tags/related' %>
```

**views/tags/_related.html.erb**

```
   <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <%= link_to image_tag(post.image.url(:small)), post%>
      <%= link_to post.title, post %>
   <% end %>
```

This is wrong because ALL posts are being indexed within the **_related.html.erb** partial -- not just the posts with the same tag(s) being shown within that singular post's show view. I thought since I defined @posts as Post.tagged_with(@tag.name) in the tags controller this would work, but no.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I have very basic knowledge of ROR*

I faced the same issue today and found out that it seems there is a method defined for this, the find_related_tags method.

So I guess that you could use in your related views something like:

**views/tags/_related.html.erb**

```
  <% @posts.find_related_tags.each do |post| %>
      <%= link_to image_tag(post.image.url(:small)), post%>
      <%= link_to post.title, post %>
   <% end %>
```

In case you want to limit the results you can use ... @posts.find_related_tags.first(3).each...
Most probably there is a better way to limit the results output, not sure, but this is what I used.

you can find more info here:

[rubydoc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/acts_as_20ggable/ActiveRecord/Acts/Taggable/SingletonMethods#find_related_tags-instance_method)

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to do a has_many relationship from post to posts, through tags.

I would create a method on the `Post` model that generates an array of related posts.

```
def related_posts
  post_ary = Post.tagged_with(self.tags, :any => true)
  post_ary.uniq.delete(self)
end
```

Note key things in that method:

- you don't want to include the post itself in the list of related posts - hence the `.delete(self)`
- `acts_as_taggable_on` gem provides some nice methods for searching - you should read up on them and see if there's anything else you want to use

Then use it in your view

```
<h3>Read more posts about: <%= render @post.tags %></h3>

<!-- This is where I want to display related posts: -->
<%= render 'tags/related', locals { post: @post} %>
```

And in your partial

```
<% post.related_posts.each do |rp| %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(rp.image.url(:small)), rp %> 
  ...
%>
```

footnotes:

You should present the same controller actions as you do views -- you've provided us with the post/index action but the post/show view.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed and helpful response. I have 2 questions: 1) do I need has_many :related posts in the post model? 2) I have placed the post.rb code you provided in my post model. For some reason I just can't figure out, I'm getting an "undefined method `related_posts'" error when I load a post show page. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Thank you again for your time.

Comment: 1) No, you definitely DO NOT need a has_many related posts.  `related_posts` is a method, not a relationship.  2) Open up the rails console (`rails c`), load a post with `post = Post.first`, and then type `post.related_posts`

Comment: Thanks. I am getting this error in console too: "NoMethodError: undefined method `posts' for #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag:0x007f88a7eb3f48>"

Comment: Oh.  Then the taggable gem doesn't work as I assume it did...  Looking at docs, you should use the `.tagged_with()` method.  I will edit my answer.